# Cannot send headers; headers already sent error

Tags: product

**In My Magento store front end when I'm trying to create a product return request then following error comes.**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:153:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /app/code/community/Jayje/Rma/controllers/IndexController.php, line 47";i:1;s:1684:"#0 lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the extension - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/return-merchant-authorization.html (I think that this is it). In **app/code/community/Jayje/Rma/controllers/IndexController.php** on **line 47** there is:

```
print_r($arrParams);  ;
```

So delete this and it should be okay. This is some debugging that the developer forgot to remove.

Answer (score 0):

`app/code/community/Jayje/Rma/controllers/IndexController.php`

check this file some thing is `print` or `echo`. before the redirecting on other page.

Comment: { 

         $this->loadLayout();     

          $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

          if(!$session->isLoggedIn()) {

             $this->_redirect('customer/account/login/');

          }

          $this->renderLayout();

    }

Comment: `{ $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); if(!$session->isLoggedIn()) { $this->_redirect('customer/account/login/'); } 
 $this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout(); }` i think load layout may be problem.

Comment: Not working. Actually extension work fine in xampp

Comment: this is not about the extension it is php error. try to refresh cache too after that...